# System.Net.WebException when attempting webRequest.GetRequestStream while attempting to POST to RESTful service

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Using values against chrome's Advanced REST Client works fine when I feed in the same values and settings as used in my dot net 4.0 app.

On the other hand, when I attempt to consume a clients REST service from dotnet, my app immediately falls over when I call webRequest.GetRequestStream() with exception {"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."}, HREsult -2146233079, inner exception ""Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream." HResult -2146232800
Here's my code, but I've changed some values to protect my client's details.

When the code attempts to getrequeststream(), my fiddler monitor raises 2 entries to show my app is contacting the server. Shouldn't it just be creating a whole packet with authorization headers and the json content and sending it in a single call? or is this how POST usually works? Fiddler never picks up activity from chrome's ARC so I can't compare.

I've tried WebRequest, webclient, httpwebrequest etc and can't get any of them working. (I can't use the new webclient class as my main app is dotnet 4.0). I run VS in administrator mode. How can chrome's Advanced REST client work, but mine not? What's the difference?

```
string parsed = @"    {
  "data": {
    "workoutDate": "2015-01-23",
    "exerciseType": "TREADMILL",
    "workoutDuration": 1456,
    "distance": 1382.0,
    "energyConsumed": 567068.0,
    "averageHeartRate": 75.0,
    "averageSpeed": 1.0
  },
  "user": {
    "email": "bumbly.boms@pdd.com",
    "firstName": "Len",
    "lastName": "BlTestoomers",
    "gender": "MALE",
    "dateOfBirth": "1984-10-27"
  }
}";
  // Add authorization headers
  string authentication = string.Format("Authorization: RRgym SNUFFCENTRE:{0}:gymId246", EyupSecurityKey.GenerateAuthenticationKey());

  // Convert the parsed string into byte[]
  byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parsed);

  string addr = "https://equipment.test.pogram.uk/acr-rest/equipment/v1/workout/endurance";

  WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(addr);
  webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
  webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
  webRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
  webRequest.Headers.Add(authentication);

  Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
  // Send the data.
  newStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
  newStream.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll post this to help others that might have the same problem.

I've been contacted by the client to say that my problem may be because their server is set to a higher security level than base visual studio. (Chrome ARC must be handling it ok).

So I had to set 
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
just before creating my webrequest.

Unfortunately that's a protocol that's not supported in dotnet4.0 but is in 4.5 so I need to come up with a fix. But that's another day :)